# why my program is showing this compilation error?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

i am learning c++ and just reached pointers and after reading about i started practicing about it
and i am stuck at multidimensional array and pointers .the problem at which i am stuck is that my program is not printing 2nd array elements it is also giving some errors i tried to find solution but can't find one I have share picture of my program you can look at it link is below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14CwD.png)

thankyou

Comment: `ptrarr` is a pointer to `int`, `*ptrarr` is a `int` and `**ptrarr` makes no sense, why do you dereference twice?

Comment: i went to many websites and it showed me same thing . please tell how to fix it

Comment: Please edit your question, remove the image of your code and paste your code as text into your question.

Comment: wait i'll do the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[2][3];
    arr[0][0]=1;
    arr[0][1]=8;
    arr[0][2] = 4;
    arr[1][0]=3;
    arr[1][1] = 6;
    arr[1][2] = 54;
    int* ptrarr=&arr[0][0];
    
    cout<<*(*(ptrarr+1)+1);

    return 0;
}
```

What essentially your are doing is assigning `ptrarr` with address of `arr[0][0]`. In the `cout` statement, the `ptrarr` increments the address to `arr[0][1]` then deferences it (outputs the value of that address) which is `8 (arr[0][1]=8)` and then, you are again derefencing it which means nothing since you have a value now and not the address.

This can solve your error

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[2][3];
    arr[0][0]=1;
    arr[0][1]=8;
    arr[0][2] = 4;
    arr[1][0]=3;
    arr[1][1] = 6;
    arr[1][2] = 54;
    int* ptrarr=&arr[0][0];
    
    cout<<*(ptrarr+ (rowNumber*COL) + colNumber));

    return 0;
}
```

Where `rownumber` and `colnumber` is the position where you want to access and `COL` is the total number of columns. In your case it is `3`.

So if you want to output, `arr[1][2]`, you will do

```
cout<<*(ptr+(1*3)+2);
```

Comment: sir but i want value from second array

Comment: What output are you actually expecting?

Comment: the output that i am expecting is 54

Comment: I have edited the answer now. It will work now. For getting output as `54`, `cout<<*(ptrarr+(1*3)+2)` since it is at arr[1][2]

Comment: can you please explain what it means??it will be helpful

Comment: Basically the elements in the 2D array are stored consecutively in memory, and `ptrarr` points to the beginning of it. Therefore you can do it in the above way as an 1D array. That's why we don't use something like **ptrarr, as it's not "a pointer to a pointer", even it's a two-dimensional array.